# java.lang.VerifyError when using vaadin and vaadin-server

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, verifyerror

For a project I am working on, which depends on vaadin-6.8.12, I would like to use the Page/JavaScript classes included in the vaadin-server-7.0.6 JAR.

However, when I include vaadin-server, I get a java.lang.VerifyError when attempting to use the Page.getCurrent() method.

To illustrate this, I wrote a small test program which exhibits the same behaviour:

```
import com.vaadin.server.Page;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            Page page = Page.getCurrent();
            System.out.println(page);
    }
}
```

I have set the classpath in a file (the JAR files and Main.class are in the same folder):

```
vaadin-6.8.12.jar:vaadin-server-7.0.6.jar:vaadin-shared-7.0.6.jar:vaadin-
shared-deps-1.0.2.jar:vaadin-theme-compiler-7.0.6.jar
```

Then run the program like this:

```
java -cp $(cat vaadin.classpath):. Main
```

When run, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
com/vaadin/server/Page, method: getJavaScript signature:
()Lcom/vaadin/ui/JavaScript;) Incompatible argument to function
at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

However if I reverse the order of vaadin-6.8.12 and vaadin-server-7.0.6, I do not get the java.lang.VerifyError.

I have tried the same test for different versions of vaadin and vaadin-server, always with the same result as above.

vaadin is not listed as dependency of vaadin-server (and vice-versa) in the maven POM. Im am using JDK version 1.6.0_32. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: i am not really sure, what you are up to, but at a first glance this looks really wrong. just because you don't have "dependencies" shown, does not mean, that you have e.g. the same classes in the same package and that code there beeing dependent on code of the same "jar".  just mixing the classpath would explain this different behaviour just fine: the classloaders picks the first class and you get random errors.

Comment: i'd rather pick that code by source files and put it in my code (if licencing allows) instead of mixing major versions.  after all there still is code compiled by GWT for the client.  if you expect something like the `@JavaScript` annotation to work between 6 and 7, you might be up for a challenge...

Comment: Thank for your reply cfrick. I hadn't considered including the code directly in my project. Also you are right, I should have created a test maven project instead, to insure that the required dependencies were all included. From yours and Henri's reply, I think the major mistake is to try and mix Vaadin versions. I'm just confused why there aren't compatible versions available from the maven central repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot combine Vaadin 6 and Vaadin 7 that way. If you want to use features from Vaadin 7 you need to migrate the whole application to use Vaadin 7.

If you want to execute some JavaScript from server side, Vaadin 6 has the `Window.executeJavaScript()` method that you can try to use.

Comment: Thank you Henri, that's just what I needed. There don't seem to be any common versions of vaadin and vaadin-server available on the maven central repository, thats why I mixed versions.

Comment: vaadin is only for Vaadin 6 and vaadin-server for Vaadin 7. Please accept the correct answer then.